# Multiple Choice Quiz TypeError: Question() takes no arguments

Tags: python, python-3.8

Hi I'm new to python I keep getting TypeError: Question() takes no arguments

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/adriankelsey/PycharmProjects/LearningPython/Building a Multiple Choice Quiz/app.py", line 10, in 
Question(question_prompts[0], "a"),
TypeError: Question() takes no arguments

This is Question.py

```
class Question:
    def __int__(self, prompt, answer):
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.answer = answer
```

This is in app.py

```
    from Question import Question
    
    question_prompts = [
        "What color are apples?\n(a) Red/green\n(b) Purple\n(c) Orange\n\n",
        "What color are bananas?\n(a) Teal\n(b) Magenta \n(c) Yellow\n\n",
        "What color are strawberries?\n(a) Yellow\n(b) Red\n(c) Blue\n\n"
    ]
    
    questions = [
        Question(question_prompts[0], "a"),
        Question(question_prompts[1], "c"),
        Question(question_prompts[2], "b"),
    ]
    
    def run_test(questions):
        score = 0
        for question in questions:
            answer = input(question.prompt)
            if answer == question.answer:
                score += 1
        print("You got " + str(score + "/" + str(len(questions) + " correct")))
    
    run_test(questions)
```

Answer (score 1):

it's `def __init__(self, prompt, answer)`

and **not**

`def __int__(self, prompt, answer)`

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo use `__init__` instead of `__int__`. Because the method `__init__` is not defined, it is like your class `Question` takes no arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error. You made a typo when initializing your class:

`def __int__` instead of  `def __init__`